# Why does the resistor need to be placed before the junction in an RTL NOT Circuit

Tags: transistors, resistors, inverter, rtl, junction

I am trying to implement a simple inverter using transistors. I am confused why placing the resistor between the junction and the LED will not work, but placing the resistor before the junction does work. Could someone explain this to me? Thanks.
[image]

I also tried simulating it in circuit.js, which gave me more intuition, but I still don't understand why current goes through both branches in the faulty circuit when the switch is closed: http://tinyurl.com/27lvrxce.

In particular, I thought that the faulty circuit (C1), when input is high, would be equivalent to circuit C3 in the photo below. While I do understand that creates a short circuit, you can see that branch 2 (the one with the diode) of C3 is low (low voltage relative to ground), whereas branch 2 of C1 (the not working circuit) is high (high voltage relative to ground). [image] Why is C1 not equivalent to C3?

Comment: the second  circuit shorts out the power supply

Comment: In the second circuit, do you know how to calculate the total voltage across R7 and D3? (As a hint, calculating the voltage is likely to be much, much easier than it may seem at first glance.)

Comment: michael, The *working* circuit is really a resistor being used as a current limiter for an LED, which would always be **ON** except that a transistor has been added in parallel to the LED, diverting the LED current away from the LED and through the transistor when the transistor is **ON**. I don't exactly call this RTL because the 220 Ohm resistor wasn't designed for RTL but was instead designed for the LED. Which makes it an LED circuit with an added transistor to bypass its current, instead. That's how it looks to me. Not like RTL.

Comment: Hi Tanner, I think the voltage is 1V?

Comment: Hi periblepsis, sorry for the misusage. My confusion about why the not working circuit keeps the output high when the input is high still stands.

Answer (score 1):

From your bottom circuit, removing everything except transistor and voltage source makes things clearer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi32ig.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we treat the transistor as a kind of switch, when that switch is closed, it becomes a dead short-circuit across the supply, and lots of current flows. In the short term that may or may not have the desired effect of switching off LED current by routing it "around" (bypassing) the LED. What actually happens depends on the properties of the voltage source and transistor, but this is now a battle to the death. If I were a betting man, my money's on the voltage source, with the transistor losing the fight.

Redrawing your correct, upper circuit, with a slightly different layout (same connectivity, just different component placement, might make it easier to see where currents are flowing in the two states transistor "off" (left), and transistor "on" (right). Again, I'm treating the transistor like a switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUdGsK.png)</sup>

Unlike the dead-short scenario, in both cases here the current that flows is limited by R1, to some reasonable and safe value, but the path that it takes will depend on the state of Q1.

That's the answer to your question; in your second circuit there's a dead short across the power supply when the transistor is on, and what happens is anyone's guess. In your first circuit, though, current is *always* limited by R1, and nothing is stressed to breaking point.

Above left, with Q1 "off" (you can remove it from the circuit, without changing anything, since it's quite literally an "open cicruit"), clearly current will have to take the path via the LED.

Above right, with Q1 "on", the path through Q1 has much lower resistance than offered by the LED, and the vast bulk of current will pass via Q1 instead, starving the LED. Another way to envisage this is that when Q1 is on, the short-circuit is now across the LED, which will reduce the voltage across the LED to near-zero.

Comment: Thanks! I think I am starting to see, the short circuit causes an indeterminate state because as resistance goes to zero, current goes to infinity. If I consider the resistor equation for parallel circuits: 1/R_t = 1/R_1 + 1/R_2, R_1 in the dead-short scenario is near zero, so R_t is near zero? I will follow up with a more comprehensive summary of my understanding in the morning.

Comment: @michael_fortunato that is exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

When the transistor is "on", there is a low voltage across it, a couple hundred mV. A LED has a somewhat more than a volt, up to a few volts, depending on the color (IR can be a bit less than a volt).

In your first circuit, since the voltage across the transistor is less than the LED's turn-on voltage (where it goes from very faintly glowing to usefully bright), and since R1 limits the fairly insubstantial current, what current does flow will go through the transistor and the LED will not turn on (it won't turn on appreciably anyways with a 1V supply).

In your second circuit, the transistor will pass a few hundred microamps, which goes right back to the supply. The LED/resistor combo is connected directly across the terminals of the power supply which can provide infinite current according to the simulator so an extra few microamps is literally nothing; the voltage on the power supply's terminals doesn't change so the current through the LED doesn't change.

Comment: Are you saying that the current between the collector and emitter in the second circuit is a few hundred microamps, but because the resistance is zero, the current of the total circuit is infinite, so the majority of that current goes to the LED (hence it stays on?).

Comment: The voltage source is ideal (infinite current) and the wires are ideal (zero resistance), so both the transistor and LED/resistor pair take as much current as they are "supposed to", and one does not influence the other.